# Extend number of arguments in std::hypot

Tags: c++, c++11, mathematics, template-meta-programming

I would like to call `std::hypot` with many arguments (not just 2 or 3).

Mandatory requirements:

- fast
- run at compile time when possible

Non-mandatory requirement:

- avoid overflow

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>


template <typename T>
constexpr T sum2(const T v) {
  return v * v;
}

template<typename T1, typename... Ts>
constexpr T1 sum2(const T1 v1, const Ts... rest)
{
  return v1 * v1 + sum2(rest...);
}

template <typename T1, typename... Ts>
constexpr T1 qsum(const T1 v1, const Ts... v)
{
  return sqrt(sum2(v1, v...));
}


int main()
{
  double a = 10.;
  std::cout << qsum(1., a) << std::endl;
}
```

One bad thing is when I ask `qsum(1, 1.)` since the first argument is `int` and so the output. I would like that in this case the inputs are cast to the safer common type.

Comment: Just as a note: `POSIX specifies that underflow may only occur when both arguments are subnormal and the correct result is also subnormal **(this forbids naive implementations)** ` Also note the standard one only works on values of the same type (so standard promotion is forced before the function is called. So your template should only have one `T`.

Comment: Lots more info here: `http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let me just say that `qsum` is a really bad name for a generic `hypot` function. I would have called it... `hypot`! In fact, I'm going to do that in this answer, because it'll make the code a lot easier to read.

Well, I'll call it `my_hypot`, because we'll be including `<cmath>`, and I don't want any confusion over whether we're accidentally referring to the standard library's 2-argument `hypot`.

---

You have an anti-pattern in your code: you're writing things like `T sum2(const T v)` instead of `T sum2(T v)`. The former is exactly equivalent to the latter as far as the *caller* of the function is concerned; but for the *implementor* of the function, the latter is strictly better:

- It's less typing, and more importantly, less reading for the maintainer/reviewer.
- It doesn't inhibit move semantics.
- For these reasons, it's idiomatic C++; and therefore you should follow the idiom because breaking idioms for no reason is distracting to the maintainer/reviewer.

---

I think you could simplify your code by "thinking in C++17" and then working backwards to lower the resulting code back down to C++11.

In C++17, with [fold-expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), your function would be just

```
template<typename... Ts> constexpr auto my_hypot(Ts... vs) {
    return sqrt(( (vs * vs) + ... ));
}
```

In C++14, though, we don't have fold-expressions, so we're going to have to replace the construct `(pattern + ...)` with some kind of function call; say, `sum(pattern...)`. So our C++14 code should look like

```
template<typename... Ts>
constexpr auto my_hypot(Ts... vs) {
    return sqrt(sum( (vs * vs)... ));
}
```

In C++11, we need to use the "trailing `decltype`" trick to get the compiler to accept that code, since C++11 can't deduce return types (except in lambdas).

```
template<typename... Ts>
constexpr auto my_hypot(Ts... vs) -> decltype(sqrt(sum( (vs * vs)... ))) {
    return sqrt(sum( (vs * vs)... ));
}
```

And there we go! Other than writing the `sum` function, this is a very straightforward translation of the code you *want* to write, into code that should be acceptable to a C++11 compiler.

---

However, I think your code as it stands is a bit sketchy, because of the overflow issue. `my_hypot(65536, 65536, 1.0)` should yield `92681.9`, not undefined behavior! To mitigate that issue, I agree with you that casting all of the parameters to `common_type` would be a good idea. Let's implement that.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename CT> constexpr CT sum() { return {}; }

template<typename CT, typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr CT sum(T v, Ts... vs)
{
    return v + sum<CT>(vs...);
}

template <typename... Ts>
constexpr auto my_hypot(Ts... vs) -> typename std::common_type<Ts...>::type
{
    using CT = typename std::common_type<Ts...>::type;
    return sqrt(sum<CT>( (CT(vs) * CT(vs))... ));
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << my_hypot(10., 10) << std::endl;
  std::cout << my_hypot(10, 10, 10.) << std::endl;
  std::cout << my_hypot(10, 10) << std::endl;
}
```

This is all the same straightforward code as before, with the possible exception of `sum<CT>()`. Here we're making an overload set of `sum<CT>()` (with no arguments) and `sum<CT>(T, Ts...)` (with at least one argument). By construction, both `T` and all the elements of `Ts...` will always be `CT`; we could `static_assert` that, if we wanted to. `sum<CT>()` returns a value-initialized `CT` (i.e., the "zero" of whatever type `CT` happens to be); I used `{}` instead of `0` just in case `CT` is some wacky bignum type that doesn't have an implicit conversion from `int`. Depending on your assumptions, `0` might be the safer choice.

---

The really nice thing about this code is that because we constructed it by starting with C++17 and moving backward, it's easy to take *this* code and migrate it *forward* to C++14 (by removing the trailing return types) and then to C++17 (by replacing the implementation of `sum` with a one-liner, or inlining it altogether) as your compiler catches up. Looking at your original code, I think it would be a little bit harder to disentangle the C++11isms from the "business logic" of how to compute `hypot`. For example, you've got the subexpression `v * v` repeated in two different places, for no good reason that I can see. You could have factored that out... or rather, not factored it *in* in the first place! :) [Don't repeat yourself.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: `qsum` is "sum in quadrature" or "euclidean distance". hypotenuse is just for triangles...

Comment: Removing the trailing return type in `my_hypot` might change the output of this function. In fact, your implementation is wrong. Suppose you call `my_hypot(1, 1)`. Then, `CT` is `int` and hence, in presence of *your* trailing return type, the output will be implicitly casted to `int`; which is not the desired behavior. So, you need to change the trailing return type to be the type of the result of the `std::sqrt` invocation.

Comment: And let me note that your code still doesn't handle possible overflow issues as `std::hypot` does. Casting to `std::common_type_t<Ts...>` won't help in any practical application where usually all `Ts` are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried to render it in `constexpr` form, but I would consider an extended version of the [Moler and Morrison algorithm for computing a hypotenuse robustly](http://blogs.mathworks.com/images/cleve/moler_morrison.pdf). Section 2 of the paper shows the basic algorithm for 2 dimensional computation, and section 3 shows how to extend the 2D version to work with arbitrary dimensions.

For what it's worth, I posted a [C implementation of the 2D algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3506633/179910) to Stack Overflow some years ago.

I would take particular note of the fact that you can typically use a fixed number of iterations of the 2D algorithm, which I believe will probably make the code somewhat easier to render in a form that can be executed at compile time if needed (though I'll admit I'm uncertain about that).

The primary advantage of this algorithm is being much more immune to overflow (and underflow). If the actual distance won't fit in your destination type, then overflow becomes almost unavoidable, of course, but that's about the only time this will overflow (or underflow).

This is also relatively fast, at least as a general rule. In my experience, a single square root (alone) is often slower than computing the hypotenuse as a whole with this (though that testing has only been with the 2D version, not the multi-dimensional version). On the other hand, if you have a lot of dimensions, you may lose that advantage. A naive method does a lot of multiplications and additions, then one square root at the end. This does something in the same general speed range as a square root for each term instead.

By contrast, more obvious methods involve squaring the inputs, then summing the squares. This can result in overflow if the inputs are large or underflow if they're small. If we have a large number of dimensions, the summation should probably be done with something like Kahan's summation algorithm to maintain precision. That typically slows the summation by a factor of 2 (or so) compared to naive summation.

Comment: Upvoted for interestingness, but I'm not sure this counts as a code review. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree with Loki's comments if you wish to duplicate `std::hypot`.  But, finding a "safer common type" is way more fun than having a common type for all arguments right from the start.

For this, you could use a trailing return type with `decltype` to make each expression-returning template function return its expression's promoted type, rather than whatever type the function's first argument has.

The example below is kind of ugly because each function's expression appears in the function body and in the decltype, so there is room for improvement, but it demonstrates the basic idea.

This prints `10.0499` on both lines, where the original would print `10.0499`, then `10`, because the second `qsum` call's first argument is an `int`.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
constexpr T sum2(const T v) {
  return v * v;
}

template<typename T1, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto sum2(const T1 v1, const Ts... rest) -> decltype(v1 * v1 + sum2(rest...))
{
  return v1 * v1 + sum2(rest...);
}

template <typename T1, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto qsum(const T1 v1, const Ts... v) -> decltype(sqrt(sum2(v1, v...)))
{
  return sqrt(sum2(v1, v...));
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << qsum(1.0, 10) << std::endl;
  std::cout << qsum(10, 1.0) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: is the `sqrt` in `decltype` really executed?

Comment: @RuggeroTurra no, the argument to `decltype` is never evaluated. However, despite having no *value* (because it's not e*valu*ated), it certainly has a *type* (which is all decl*type* cares about).

Comment: In C++14, you could reasonably omit the trailing return types and just use `auto` return type deduction. The `-> decltype(...)` stuff matters for SFINAE purposes, but I'd argue that you could *reasonably* ignore SFINAE if you wanted to.